# Google play Android app updates delays - Closed tracks channel

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, app-update

I can't quite understand how Google Play propagates app updates when a new app version is release.

My scenario is the following: I have a B2B app deployed on Google Play in the "Closed tracks" channel. On each device of the closed track there's the same Google Play account configured and I can see the entire fleet of devices in my Google Play. On some devices the last version of the app is already installed and the automatic update of the old version has been quite fast, however on other devices the update is very slow (2 weeks or more, on some still no update). What are the criteria used by Google to spread out the updates? I can't find precise info Googling.